# Regex escape escape characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex

So I have this regex that works on regex101.com

```
(?:[^\#\\S\\+]*)
```

It matches the first from first#second.

Whenever I try to use my regex with PHP's preg_replace I don't get the result I expect.

So far I tried it via preg_quote():

```
\(\?\:\[\^\\#\\S\\\+\]\*\)
```

And tried it with escaping the original \\ with 4 \'s:

```
\(\?\:\[\^\\#\\\\S\\\\\+\]\*\)
```

Still no success. Am I doing something fundamentaly wrong?

I'm just using:

```
preg_replace("/$regex/", "", $string);
```

All my other regexes that don't need so many escape chars work perfectly that way.

Comment: What is your input string like? What are you trying to match? What makes you sure `(?:[^\#\\S\\+]*)` works at regex101?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For example firstpart#secondpart. I try to match the firstpart.

Comment: Ok, look, it [does not match `firStpart#secondpart` correctly](https://regex101.com/r/kD8kA6/1), right? What are the requirements? Why not `explode` with `#`? If you want to use regex, perhaps, you can use `preg_match('~^[^#\s]+~', $s, $match)`, but exploding looks cleaner.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just tried that, works like a charm. Still new to PHP, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `(?:[^\#\\S\\+]*)` in a `preg_match` in PHP, both in a single or double quoted string literal, the `\\S` is parsed as a non-whitespace pattern. `[^\S]` is equal to `\s`, i.e. it matches whitespace.

The `preg_quote()` function is only meant to be used to make any string a literal one for a regex, it just escapes all chars that are sepcial regex metacharacters / operators (like `(`, `)`, `[`, etc.), thus you should not use it here.

While you could use a regex to match 1+ chars other than whitespace and `#` from the start of a string like [`preg_match('~^[^#\s]+~', $s, $match)`](https://regex101.com/r/56PVo1/1), you can just `explode` your input string  with `#` and get the 0th item.